# How can i add plugins in x64dbg?

Tags: debuggers, x64dbg, plugin

I am trying to add 'xAnalyzer' plugin into it but after copying the files, I can't see it in debugger.
Its installation instructions are not working.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please elaborate so we can attempt to help without starting from zero.

Comment: have you done exactly what they are writing on the github? I've just did it an plugin is visible w/o any problems.

Answer (score 6):

#### Download

Download the files

- apis_def.zip
- xAnalyzer.dp32
- xAnalyzer.dp64

from
[here](https://github.com/ThunderCls/xAnalyzer/releases)

#### Steps

- Copy **xAnalyzer.dp32** to x32/plugins directory
- Copy **xAnalyzer.dp64** to x64/plugins directory
- Create a folder named "**apis_def**" in both **x32/plugins** & **x64/plugins** directory
- Now copy the contents of "**apis_def.zip**" into both **"apis_def"** folder

All done!

Answer (score 0):

After the steps mentioned by @GameMaster Greatee look under the "Plugins" menu in the main x64dbg window or in the secondary menu in the Disasm window as well for an "xAnalyzer" entry.
Source:https://github.com/ThunderCls/xAnalyzer